# UITableView load sections independently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a table view which takes time in loading and has one tableviewcell selected. I want to display that pre-selected cell in a separate section before the whole tableview loads up. I have the data to add to the cell. One ugly solution i can think of is having two separate tableviews but that wouldnt be a clean solution. Any suggestions, how can I better handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Store a BOOL value in your controller, perhaps named "dataLoaded". Then, update your table view data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (self.dataLoaded) {
        return 1; //Just the pre-selected cell
    }
    return 2; //However many sections for when data loaded
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section==0) {
        return 1; //Your pre-selected cell
    else
        return self.numberOfData; //Number of cells in other section after data loaded
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
       //Return your pre-selected cell
    } else {
       //Data cells (after loaded)
    }
}
```

Now, in viewDidLoad, just call [tableView reloadData]. Then, call reloadData again once the data finishes loading